# How to extract query from `getServerSideProps` to separate helper file?

Tags: next.js, apollo, apollo-client

I've got several pages that I want to call a query inside of `getServerSideProps` to request the currentUser.

What I have currently is something like this:

```
import { NextPageContext } from 'next';
import { withAuth } from 'hoc/withAuth';
import { addApolloState, initializeApollo } from 'lib/apolloClient';
import { MeDocument } from 'generated/types';
import nookies from 'nookies';
import Profile from 'components/Profile';

const ProfilePage: React.FC = () => <Profile />;

export const getServerSideProps = async (
  context: NextPageContext
): Promise<any> => {
  // withAuth(context);

  const client = initializeApollo();
  const { my_token } = nookies.get(context);

  await client.query({
    query: MeDocument,
    context: {
      headers: {
        authorization: my_token ? `Bearer ${my_token}` : '',
      },
    },
  });

  return addApolloState(client, { props: {} });
};

export default ProfilePage;
```

This works, and I can verify in my Apollo devtools that the cache is being updated with the User.

When I try to move the Apollo initialization and query in to a separate file, the cache is never updated for some reason.

Inside of a `withAuth.tsx` file, I had something like this:

```
import { NextPageContext } from 'next';
import { addApolloState, initializeApollo } from 'lib/apolloClient';
import { MeDocument } from 'generated/types';
import nookies from 'nookies';

export const withAuth = async (context: any,) => {
  const client = initializeApollo();
  const { gc_token } = nookies.get(context);

  await client.query({
    query: MeDocument,
    context: {
      headers: {
        authorization: gc_token ? `Bearer ${gc_token}` : '',
      },
    },
  });

  return addApolloState(client, { props: {} });
};
```

With this, all I have to do is call `withAuth()` in the `getServerSideProps`. There are no errors, however the cache doesn't update.

How can I extract that code to a separate file correctly?

Comment: I'm think you just need to `await withAuth(context);` in getServerSideProps?

Comment: I wish it were that simple, but that doesn't appear to be working either.

Comment: You need the `return` statement when calling `withAuth` inside `getServerSideProps`, i.e., `return withAuth(context);`.

Comment: Doh! I think you're right, I hate that it was that simple. Thanks @juliomalves!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @juliomalves in the comments, I simply forgot to return the `withAuth` function!

Here's how it looks now:

*pages/index.tsx*

```ts
export const getServerSideProps = async (
  context: NextPageContext
): Promise<any> => await withAuth(context);
```

*withAuth.tsx*

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types */
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/client';
import redirectToLogin from 'helpers/redirectToLogin';
import { addApolloState, initializeApollo } from 'lib/apolloClient';
import { MeDocument } from 'generated/types';
import nookies from 'nookies';

export const withAuth = async (context: any) => {
  const session = await getSession(context);
  const isUser = !!session?.user;

  // no authenticated session
  if (!isUser) redirectToLogin();

  const client = initializeApollo();
  const { token } = nookies.get(context);

  await client.query({
    query: MeDocument,
    context: {
      headers: {
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
      },
    },
  });

  return addApolloState(client, { props: {} });
};
```